# Cannot figure out how to update column in a table depending on a group of column/s in same table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, cursor, sql-update, common-table-expression

I am trying to update the column total(Totl) as SUM(Volume) divided-by COUNT(*) , for only the rows that are in a group(Week) of column/s, in a table of 4 different fruits(Fruit_Volume) and a lot of records(with more attributes like buyers, growing areas..), I only want to generate values for Apples(Item_Name) that are Organic(Fruit_Type), grouped by Week(date). 
-TIA

```
UPDATE Fruit_Volume
SET Totl = B.Totl
FROM (SELECT SUM(Volume)/COUNT(*) Totl FROM Fruit_Volume
    WHERE Item_Name LIKE 'Apple%' AND Fruit_Type = 'Organic'
    GROUP BY Week -- I feel the need to group by Item_Group, Fruit_Type
     ) as B
WHERE Item_Name LIKE 'Apple%' AND Fruit_Type = 'Organic'
```

Comment: Your subquery will return multiple rows when you are grouping by week so you can't update with that. If it returned one value it would work I believe

Comment: sample schema and data with expected output would be useful

Comment: @aaryan Don't use group by (it gives multiple results) for which you wont be able to update the Totl field.
Why is there a need to group by week?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming here that you want to record a total common to multiple rows, for the same week, for the same product(s), and then apply this to the fruit affected by the week.

```
UPDATE fv
SET fv.Totl = B.Totl
FROM 
    Fruit_Volume fv
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT 
          SUM(Volume) / COUNT(*) Totl,
          [Week]
        FROM
          Fruit_Volume
        WHERE 
          Item_Name LIKE 'Apple%' AND Fruit_Type = 'Organic'
        GROUP BY 
          [Week]
     ) as B
     ON fv.[Week] = b.[Week]
WHERE 
    Item_Name LIKE 'Apple%' AND Fruit_Type = 'Organic';
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/235a2/1)

**Edit** 
The query can be `DRY'd` up a bit by updating through a [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx).

```
WITH cte AS 
(
  SELECT 
    *
  FROM
    Fruit_Volume
  WHERE 
    Item_Name LIKE 'Apple%' AND Fruit_Type = 'Organic'

)
UPDATE cte
    SET cte.Totl = B.Totl
    FROM 
        cte
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT 
              SUM(Volume) / COUNT(*) Totl,
              [Week]
            FROM
              cte
            GROUP BY 
              [Week]
         ) as B
         ON cte.[Week] = b.[Week];
```

[Updated fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/235a2/5)

Comment: Thankyou. And you are right, I am trying to maintain a total common to multiple tables for all fruits as well as individual fruits.